# Interacting with a UIViewController that is underneath a modal presented VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I'm implementing a solution whereas I've got a parent `UIViewController` in which presents a `UIPageViewController` modally in `viewDidAppear()`. `UIPageViewController` enables sliding between 3 viewcontrollers, whereas the center one has the backgroundColor set to `UIColor.clear` so that I can see the first and parent VC through it. This works great, apart from the fact that I can't interact with it.

**What I've tried:**

- Setting the user interaction enabled property to false for the empty (placeholder) viewcontroller
- Presenting the pageVC with .overCurrentContext as style
- Presenting the pageVC by adding it as a child viewcontroller to the parent
- Looked into overriding some methods, but I'm not sure how to implement this

The idea to solve it was to either have the overlaying views to ignore their touch events, but later it may seem like an idea to have them delegate or somehow send the touch events further back in the view hierarchy.

Nevertheless, I can't figure it out and was hoping if any of you could help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say "interact" what precisely do you mean?  For it's view to react/change based on events (touch, or otherwise) from the paging controller??

Comment: @BonanzaDriver the idea of the whole setup is very similar to a completely "normal" pageviewcontroller setup, but the effect makes it seem like the center VC position is fixed while the side VCs kind of slides of it. When the pageVC displays the center (clear VC), you can see the fixed VC through it - which contains a `UITableView` that I'd like to interact with, e.g. scrolling, selecting, etc

Comment: Based on the description there are a couple of ways of handling this; at first blush, I'd suggest setting gesture recognizers on the paging controller and pass along received events/custom messages to your parent.  The parent could either act as a delegate to the paging, or you could setup a few custom closures.  Either way, though, it's about passing along the information to the parent that the paging received.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver so basically I got a `UIPanGestureRecongizer` set up, and I'll be creating a delegate method to talk to the parent VC from the pageVC. But once I have that in place, how can I relay those touches to actually make it seem I'm directly manipulating the parent VC?

Comment: you'll need to convert the coordinate space of the view receiving the touch events into the coordinate space of the thing you want to "simulate" the events in (your parent).  UIView.convert() API will do the job nicely.